# Neglecting Tables while PDF extraction

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, text-extraction

I am trying to make a text processing application in Java which requires text as input. Now I am extracting this input from a PDF file specified by the user. I am using PdfBox for text extraction. The problem I'm having is that a PDF file may contain tables, equations and special symbols, so the text that PdfBox extracts contains garbage at many places. Due to this my text processing app fails to give its optimum result. I wanted to know if the PDF has a specific format for a table so that I can got to the root level and exclude them while extraction. Also, on many occassions, the extracted text contains unknown characters rendered as '?' although in the actual PDF they appear to be normal alphabets. I've also tried other library - IText but the results were not satisfactory. In a nutshell, all I want is to extract simple sentences from PDF files, excluding all the other garbage. It would be great if someone could help me out here by suggesting way around this problem or another better extraction library for Java. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PDF does not have a 'table' format. Tables are constructed from lines and text, that's all. A tagged PDF may have such a tag, but these are rare.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently needed to extract text from PDFs for further processing in Java - I used the Linux command **pdftotext** - if you have this command available to you is that an option?

EDIT : just seen another post today about Apache Tika - which has a PDF (and many other) parsers. Might be useful for you. http://tika.apache.org/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion....I checked it out but seems like it gives the same text as I get using PdfBox, just in an HTML format. Also, it won't be useful to me as I'm looking to create a Java App for various platforms and not just Linux....anyway thanks for your suggestion.